# Array de JS a php codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal y tengo una duda con respecto al paso de datos a php.

Resulta que en js guardo el cambio de colores de los div(los colores inicialmente son cargados a través de una consulta a una bd) en un array, con el código y el color(pueden ser 2, estos los represento con 0 o 1).

Lo que necesito es que al presionar un botón, se actualicen los estados en la bd. El problema es que no puedo enviar el array de js a php. he intentado con la  siguiente funcion:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'cursos/guardarmalla',
 data: {'actualizar' : actualizar},
 type: 'post',
 dataType:'json',
 success: function(output) {
              alert(output);
 }
 });
```

pero no se como juntar el botón y el envió del array.

función para enviar los datos:

```
function enviararray() {

$.ajax({ url: 'cursos/guardarmalla',
 data: {actualizar},
 type: 'post',
 dataType:'json',
 success: function(output) {
              alert(output);
          }
}); 
}




var actualizar=[];
function myButton_onclick(x,id) {
if(x.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 114, 144)')
{
    x.style.backgroundColor='rgb(90,237,247)';
     actualizar[id]="1";

}else{
    x.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 114, 144)';
     actualizar[id]="0";

}
console.log(actualizar)
return false;
}
```

Esas son las funciones de js que uso para modificar el array actualizar.

Este es el html del botón

```
<?php echo form_open("/cursos/guardarmalla");?>
   <div align="center"><?php echo form_submit('','Guardar Malla',"class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\" onclick=\"enviararray()\"");?></div>
<?php echo form_close()?>
```

Comment: que valor tiene **actualizar**?, te devuelve algun error desp de la peticion?, estas viendo si ese valor de **actualizar** llega al php?

Comment: actualizar es un array asociativo, tiene el código de la asignatura(es en lo que estoy trabajando) y el estado, que puede ser 0 o 1.
intente hacer un echo en el controlador pero solo me muestra un "[]" y sin errores. 
Gracias por responder.

Comment: probastes lo que te dije?

Comment: si, sigue sin funcionar, quizás tengo un error en el controlador al capturar los datos o en el boton.

Comment: basandote en mi respuesta , cambia el data, y pon **data: { actualizar: ['hola mundo']}**, y has un echo del otro lado para ver si llega ese hola mundo e ir descartando probabilidades del envio

Comment: nada , creo que mi error esta en el botón del html, pondré el código para que lo revises.

Comment: mira hagamos un debugueo pequeño , coje la función enviararray y definela así , `function enviararray(){ alert(actualizar) }` , y dale click al boton para ver que valor tiene actualizar ahí ,para saber que esta mandando a la petición, si es vació o no

Comment: Lo probé como dijiste y en la alerta no aparece nada, probé con alert(actualizar['INC100']) y ahí si me apareció el estado del código que puse.

Comment: entra al chat , en la sala Travv , para poder hablar mejor , y poderte alcarar mas rapido que en pocos minutos tengo que salir

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que cuando se realice el cambio en la función **myButton_onclick** , a la misma vez se envié la petición te quedaría así:

```
//esta es la función que enviara el arreglo con los nuevos datos
function sendActualizar(datos){

  $.ajax({ url: 'cursos/guardarmalla',
      data: {actualizar : datos},
      type: 'post',
      dataType:'json'
  }).done(function(output){
      alert(output)
  }); 
}
//la declaración de tu función myButton_onclick agregándole el envió de los datos
var actualizar=[];
function myButton_onclick(x,id) {
if(x.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 114, 144)')
{
    x.style.backgroundColor='rgb(90,237,247)';
     actualizar[id]="1";
    sendActualizar(actualizar) // manteniendo tu código llamarías aquí a la función que envía el actualizar

}else{
    x.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 114, 144)';
     actualizar[id]="0";
     sendActualizar(actualizar) // manteniendo tu código llamarías aquí a la función que envía el actualizar
}
console.log(actualizar)
return false;
}
```

Comment: También había pensado en hacerlo así, pero el envió de datos seria mas repetitivo, por eso estaba almacenando los cambios en el array para que al presionar el botón se enviara el array con  todos los cambios que se han hecho.